# Javascript regex to search for word including dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a term which looks like this

```
term = "Is this true car=truck"
```

Now I I want the get the first word on the left side of `equal` (=) which in this case is `car`

So I use a a regex to do this and this is my solution

```
leftTermOfEqual = term.match(/\w+(?= *=)/)[0]
```

This gives me `car`

But the problem occurs if there is a `dot` (.) in the left term something like

```
term = "Is this true car.myCar=truck"
```

It gives me `myCar`. But I want `car.myCar`

So I want to enhance the regex to support both the scenarios when there will or will not be a `dot`.

So I tried updating the regex to something like this

```
leftTermOfEqual = term.match(/\w+(?= [/\./]*=)/)[0]
```

But it gives me an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: In your initial RegExp, instead of `\w+` do `\S+` for any character except space, or `[a-zA-Z\.]+` for alphabetic and a dot

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov wow your suggestion for `\S+` is what I needed. You may post this as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Thank you. Just pay attention that lookaheads (`(?=...)`) may not be supported at some platforms.

Answer (score 1):

`/(\S+)=/` is enough to extract it. `\S` will stop as soon as it gets `=` to form a match.

```
term = "Is this true car.myCar=truck"
> "Is this true car.myCar=truck"
> term.match(/(\S+)=/)
(2) ["car.myCar=", "car.myCar", index: 13, input: "Is this true car.myCar=truck", groups: undefined]
> term.match(/(\S+)=/)[1]
"car.myCar"
```

If you want to capture all the left terms in a list, it's possible with `/(\S+)(?==)/g` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried `\w+(?= [/\./]*=)` does not match because it will match 1+ word characters using `\w+`

Then it asserts (non consuming) what is directly to the right is a space followed by 0+ occurrences of a dot or / (which could also be written as `[/.]`)

It does not match, because there is not space following the word chars in the example data, and `\w` does not match a dot.

---

If you want to match word characters optionally followed by a dot and more word characters, you could use a non capturing group and repeat that 0 or more times.

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?= *=)
```

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:\.\w+)*` Optionally repeat matching a dot and 1+ word chars
- `(?= *=)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is 0+ spaces followed by `=`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CpMu4/1)

```js
let pattern = /\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?= *=)/;
[
  "Is this true car=truck",
  "Is this true car.myCar=truck"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(pattern)[0]));
```

Instead of using a positive lookahead, you might also use a capturing group for the part before the equals sign, and match the equals sign plus at least a single non whitespace char.

```
([^\s=]+) *= *\S
```

- `([^\s=]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ occurrences of any char except `=` or a whitespace char
- `*= *` Match `=` between optional spaces
- `\S` Match a non whitespace char to make sure there is content following after the equals sign

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AaJf1q/1)

```js
let pattern = /([^\s=]+) *= *\S/;
[
  "Is this true car=truck",
  "Is this true car.myCar=truck"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(pattern)[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
/[\w\.]+(?= *=)/
```

Comment: This may fail if lefthand operand may contain dash (`-`)